# Just installed Google Analytics on a wordpress and visitors are not being tracked

Tags: javascript, wordpress, analytics

I added the following script to the head of all wordpress pages

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
</script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-74212290-1');
</script>
```

website is www.ice-tracks.com

is everything ok? why are visitors not being tracked?

Comment: It will take up to 24 hours for your analytics account to display visitor data. It does not show visitor data instantly. If you are wondering whether you have installed the code correctly, you can test that by sending test traffic to you website from your analytics account. You can find the button to send test traffic in analytics on the screen where you got the code.

Comment: im sorry but i cant see that button and the traffic is not being tracked

Answer (score 1):

Your script is missing reference or link to `googletagmanager` script.

Replace your current script snippet with the following snippet.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-74212290-1"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-74212290-1');
</script>
```

After you have installed above snippet into your website you can send test traffic to your website from your analytics account.

So send the test traffic, login into your google analytics account.

- Navigate to the "admin" section (the circular gear icon in left nav bar)
- Select your property in the property column (center column)
- Click on "Tracking Info" tab to expand it
- Click on "Tracking Code" under "Tracking Info" (its the first item)
- Clicking on "Tracking Code" will expand the right pane, there you can tracking id of your property.
- On the right side of the tracking id you can see the button "Send Test Traffic"
- Click on that button and your website will open in popup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: tnx, i dunno why the wordpress theme autoremoves the line u corrected missing, i add it but it gets removed when publishing :/

Comment: How are adding the script to your website? Are you using any plugin or you are directly adding it into header.php?

Comment: k, i fixed it installing a plugin called "GA Google Analytics"

Comment: i was using an option to add code to the head in the theme but dunno why it auto removed that line, also i dont know how to edit the header.php directly in the wordpress panel and i dont have ftp access to the files

Comment: Okay. If you are enabling google analytics code on website via plugin then, you should remove the script snippet that you added via option to add code via theme. If both the codes (the one you added via theme and the one via plugin) are added at the same, they will conflict.